# Optimal signal strength and quality

Tags: android, signals, gsm

I'm currently developing an application to reset your phone signal when the quality drops too low and I was wondering what the minimal Strength (dBm) requirement is to have a decent signal.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

For those who are interested: at -110 dBm (or lower), you're signal starts to drop

Comment: Actually a more reasonable value might be -100 to -103 dBm. -110 is the minimun measured value, but that is usually be too low in terms of received signal.